# Rails - Is there a way to strip HTML from all fields when saving to the database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Or do you really have to sanitize each field individually? Thanks

Comment: What's your problem with doing each one individually?  What do you mean by that?  Is it a problem if you have to loop through a collection of strings and apply `strip_tags` to each of them?

Comment: I have lets say 15 models, each with on average 5 fields. I don't want to have to sanitize in early model class for every field. I want the default save to sanatize and only if I allow it support html. Thoughts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the column metadata to loop through each column.

(From http://blog.hulihanapplications.com/browse/view/10-strip-html-in-ruby-on-rails):

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base  

 before_save :strip_html  
 def strip_html # Automatically strips any tags from any string to text typed column  
   include ActionView::Helpers::SanitizeHelper  
   for column in Product.content_columns  
     if column.type == :string || column.type == :text # if the column is text-typed  
       if !self[column.name].nil? # strip html from string if it's not empty  
         self[column.name] = strip_tags(self[column.name])  
       end  
     end  
   end  
 end
```